# "Your license does not cover Android Publishing" error

Tags: unity, build-process

I recently installed Unity 2017.1.0f3. I imported a project from an older version of Unity it worked perfectly and allowed me to build for Android. I logged in to the Asset Store through the tab in the Unity editor, now I can no longer build for Android.

This is the error I receive:

[image: Your license does not cover Android Publishing.]

I created my Unity account before Android was free. Is there a way to update my account to allow me to build with Android again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trial and error solved my problem:

1. Sign out, In the top right hand corner of the the editor click Account > Sign out [Your Name]:

[image: Sign Out.]

2. Close Unity.
3. Re-open Unity.
4. It will ask you to login and choose your licence.
5. You will now have the latest licence file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using unity hub and seems that it is the reason for the problem because I'm signed in the unity hub but not signed-in in the unity version I'm using

The solution is
1- Close current running version
2- Browse for your unity setup folder then open unity.exe (Not Open unity hub)
3- login and you can find everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my license in Unity Hub.

Preferences -> License Management -> Check for Updates